# There is no (other) country in which there are more earthquakes than (in/ ) Japan.?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence do you think is grammatically correct?

- There is no (other) country in which there are more earthquakes than Japan.
- There is no (other) country in which there are more earthquakes than **in** Japan.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding on the answer, but: you can remove "other." "There is no country with more than Japan," by itself, means that nothing tops Japan. Adding "other" would only be necessary if there is one country with more, but no *other* country with more besides that one.

Comment: "other"  is not needed because it is implied. "No country" here means "no other country" It does no harm to leave "other"  in.

Comment: I found that my textbook says "other" is not mandatory. I revised my question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't tell which answer is correct. Then I decided the accepted answer by rock-paper-scissors with my both hands. As a result, the left one won and I chose David Siegel's answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "other" here can be safely omitted, it is implied if it is absent. The first example:

> There is no (other) country in which there are more earthquakes than Japan.

is fully correct and natural. It is comparing "[any] other country" with "Japan", which seems very natural as Japan is also a country. The second example is more awkward:

> There is no (other) country in which there are more earthquakes than in Japan.

In form this seems to compare "[any] other country" with "**in** Japan",  and that does not fit properly, although it would probably be correctly understood as having the same meaning as the first example.  This could be rephrased as:

> There are more earthquakes in Japan than in any other country. (*and here "other" is needed*)

This compares "earthquakes in Japan" with "earthquakes in any other country" and so again the comparison works, because the constructions are parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at a simpler sentence that still makes a comparison:

> There are as many earthquakes in China as Japan.

This would be understood, and people might say this often in casual speech, but it's not *strictly* grammatically correct.

> There are as many earthquakes in China as **in** Japan.

Some of our sentence is being "reused." We're really saying *There are as many earthquakes in China as **there are** in Japan*, but we don't have to repeat "there are." We do, however, have to repeat the preposition.

This holds true even for the more complex sentence:

> There is no country in which there are more earthquakes than in Japan.

Note, however, that you could keep the same meaning in a totally different sentence:

> No country has more earthquakes than Japan.

This has no need for any prepositions because we've totally changed the verb.

Comment: -1 I must disagree that "There is no country in which there are more earthquakes than in Japan" is fully correct and natural. There is a comparison, but the constructions are not parallel. The "in" must go or the sentence be rephrased.